# Back button of table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode4, back-button

I have an app where you type in some text in a text field, then once the enter button is pressed, it is put into a table view. After I hit the back button of the table view I return to the previous view and the text label has whatever text I typed. To have the text cleared when I  go back I want to connect an action method to the back button of the table view. How should I do this, because the back button does not appear in interface builder so I can't just control drag?

Comment: If your table view and textview are in different view controllers then why you need to clear the textview on button action ?

Comment: how you r creating the back button.... as per my understanding through coding right...

Comment: for VXtreme, I need to clear the textview because when I hit the back button, the text remains from when i submitted an entry so it looks ugly

Comment: for spynet, I am not creating the back button through coding. WHen I create a segue on a story board, it automatically creates a back button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in  viewWillAppear or  viewDidAppear or you can do it after you save the text just clear it.

```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
            [super viewWillAppear:animated];
            [myTextField setText:@""];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller for the view with the text field you could use this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (myTextField.text.length != 0) {
        [myTextField setText:@""];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make more sense to clear the text field upon pressing the back button using something like:

method, which might look something like

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.textInput.text = @"";
}
```

on the view controller that you're navigating back to. Wach time the view appears, the text field will be cleared. Anything else you put int hat method will also be executed at that time. It would also happen when you navigate to the view for the first time but that doesn't seem like an issue here, and could easily be coded for..